# Fullcalendar Gotodate in agenda view only jumps to date of moment

Tags: fullcalendar

gotoDate

Moves the calendar to an arbitrary date.

```
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )
```

date can be a Moment object, or anything the Moment constructor accepts.

Is it possible that in agenda day view that the time part of the moment would cause the screen to scroll to the time of the moment as well. Probably with the time being at the top of the screen. This is useful for navigation after instantiation of the calendar on the screen?

Any thoughts ?

Comment: would be nice... however, currently doesn't support that. you would have to code that feature yourself.  I've done something similar for default scrollto time based upon weekday number.

Comment: Should this be quite easy to implement? I'm thinking of giving it a go by forking the code.

Comment: wasn't hard... i simply used a jquery scrollto plugin, added an 'id' to each time slot, and used the two to scroll to that slot in the `eventAfterAllRender`

Comment: I like your style. I'll have a go!